# Using styled components to style an input depending on value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I am using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) to Style a [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) Form.control element.

I am trying to work out if it is possible to style an input depending if it has a value.
For example, without a value (just placeholder) I would like the input to be grey. If the field has a value it should be white.

I've tried a bunch of variants of the below, but to no avail:

```
background: ${props =>
    props.value ? 'white' : `${props.theme.colors.greys.athens}`};
```

I have also tried the `::placeholder` styling. The problem with this is it will only style the inner placeholder parts of the input field so the full background of field is not the correct background colour.

Comment: Add the code for Input too

Comment: please accept answers which work for your use-case so the community can be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some state for if the field has a value:

```
 const [hasValue, setHasValue] = useState(false);

  function onChangeValue(event) {
    if (onChange !== null) {
      onChange();
    }
    if (event.target.value === '' || event.target.value === undefined) {
      return setHasValue(false);
    }
    return setHasValue(true);
  }
```

Then changed the styles to work off hasValue

```
background: ${props =>
    props.hasValue ? 'white' : `${props.theme.colors.greys.athens}`};
```

Comment: You probably don't need to keep another value TBH. I tried the code which I gave in a sandbox to make sure it worked. Does my solution not work for your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a state for this value for sure and in your parent wrapper, you should access this state to have the correct background color for this parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should store input value into the state and check it if it isn't null then assign its `className` to `emptyInput` class else assign it `notEmptyInput` class.So in your css file you should have two class `emptyInput` and `notEmptyInput`.This should be like that:

```
state={
   inputValue:null
}
```

In html part input should be following:

```
<Input 
   className={this.state.inputValue?notEmptyInput:emptyInput}
   onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({inputvalue:event.target.value})}}
/>
```

In css file you should have:

```
.emptyInput{
   background-color:'gray'
}
.notEmptyInput{
   background-color:'white'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe the best way is to pass your input state value as props and access it like this:**

```
background: ${props =>
props.value !== ”” ? 'white' : `$            {props.theme.colors.greys.athens}`};
```

Comment: The value prop has a defaultProp of undefined. Even if I did props.value !== '' || props.value !== undefined, it still does not work. I had to create a new state element that changes if it has a value

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";

const HomeView = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <StyleFormControl
        placeholder="placeholder"
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const StyleFormControl = styled(FormControl)`
  background: ${props => (props.value ? "white" : "gray")};
`;

export default HomeView;
```